# A way to restrict the domain of a variable?

Tags: gams-math

I have a code snippet for a transport problem like:

```
set i /1*50/
    d /1*10/

Alias(i,j,k)

parameter  
         edge(i,j)
         distance(i,j)
         possible(i,d)  'a collection of possible nodes for d'
         possible_edge(i,j,d)  'a collection of possible edge for d';

binary variable x(i,j,d);
```

I import all the edges from an excel file. But to reduce the number of variables, I'd like to create another parameter like `possible node` and `possible edge`.
suppose we run a shortest path algorithm form a source node `i` and we define `possible(i,d)` to be all `i` where `distance(i,j)` is smaller than a predefined threshold.

In other words, when the network node become larger and larger, I want to find out if there's any possibility to not define `x(i,j,d)` for every `(i,j)` combination? Like forcing to only have `x(i,j,d)$possible_edge(i,j,d)`?? Is there anything like this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can limit the domain of variables in the `model` statement, like this

```
Model m / all, x(possible_edge) /;
```

So, here, the variable `x` would be limited by the set `possible_edge` wherever it occurs in model `m`. Note, that `possible_edge` must be a set here, not a parameter.

You can find more info about this concept here: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_ModelSolve.html#UG_ModelSolve_LimitedDomain

Comment: thanks. So, for defining `possible_edge` as a set; I simpliy need to chnage the `parameter` to `set` and importing from excel would work?

Comment: Yes, that should work